# How to show "load more" or "read more" effect in recylerview at the end and show only first few cards?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I want to show only first few cards of the recyclerview and show a button such as load more or read more then on clicking on it show little more cards and so on.

What i have thought to do is making a button under recyclerview and making only first 4-5 cards in onbindViewholder() of adapter Visible and thus making other cards (or itemview as it is said in adapter class) invisible. But I don't think this would be a good approach.

Can someone suggest a good approach? I tried researching for hours, but haven't came across a near solution that is appropriate.

Comment: send to the adapter needed items quantity, and notify adapter by button click with an updated item list

Comment: yeah thanks, one more solution I came up with is giving int 5 to the adapter in constructor then returning it in getItemcount() method of the adapter then on button click incrementing it little more everytime.

Comment: if your server response has pagination, magic number 5 it's a bad approach

Comment: you have to set pagination on your server as well in you app.